# Are serving members of the UK Armed Forces banned from standing as MPs?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, military

The [BBC list of likely contenders for the upcoming Labour leadership bid](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-32654262) says of Dan Jarvis:

> elected MP [...] having resigned his commission as a major in the Parachute Regiment to contest the seat.

Are serving members of the UK Armed Forces banned from standing as MPs, or is this slightly misleading and he only resigned to (presumably) be able to spend more time on the contest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the [House of Commons Disqualification Act 1975](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1975/24/section/1), active-duty military cannot be MPs.

> 1 Disqualification of holders of certain offices and places.
>
> > (1) Subject to the provisions of this Act, a person is disqualified for membership of the House of Commons who for the time being—
> >
> > > (c) is a member of any of the regular armed forces of the Crown
> >
> > (3) In this section—
> >
> > “regular armed forces of the Crown” means the Royal Navy, the Royal Marines, the regular army (as defined by section 374 of the Armed Forces Act 2006) or the Royal Air Force.

Comment: So presumably there's a clause in it allowing MPs to be in the Reserves - I'm sure I've read about at least 1 serving MP being in the TA?

Comment: @ChrisW "Regular armed forces" distinguishes from "Reserve armed forces"

Comment: There are reservists in parliament including [James Cleverley](https://www.cleverly4braintree.com/about), [Penny Mordaunt](https://www.independent.co.uk/independentpremium/penny-mordaunt-profile-navy-mp-brexit-family-b2098860.html)